# Анимированная стрелка в формате SVG

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, css-animation

Это мой первый опыт  использования `SVG`, и я хочу узнать, возможно ли создать анимированный линейный график со стрелкой.

Я нашел несколько примеров анимированных линейных графиков без стрелок,  графиков без анимации со стрелками и анимированных прямых линий со стрелками.

Но это не совсем то, что я ищу. Я прикрепил ниже несколько примеров кода, о которых я говорил.
Кто-нибудь знает,  это возможно, есть ли решение?

1. Анимированная линия, отсутствует стрелка : [codepen](http://codepen.io/alexandraleigh/pen/jVaObd)

CSS(Less)

```
@import "lesshat";

@darkgrey:          #303030;

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background: @darkgrey;
}

.graph__wrapper{
  width: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;

  svg{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 36px 0px 0px 15px;
  }
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 3s ease-in forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

.description{
  font-family: "Roboto";
  color:lighten(@darkgrey, 50%);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 0px;
}
```

2. Анимированная  линия  (должна останавливаться в нескольких точках пути)

http://codepen.io/alexandraleigh/pen/aBVdVY

3. Я попытался добавить `path descriptions` от # 1 до # 2, и у него есть нужный конечный граф, без анимации:

http://codepen.io/alexandraleigh/pen/pNdgWR

4. Я также попытался добавить маркер стрелки с # 2 на # 1, но стрелка не поддается анимации:
   http://codepen.io/alexandraleigh/pen/aBVdVY

Я также пробовал использовать  [snapsvg.io](http://snapsvg.io/), но не увидел никаких рабочих примеров, которые  помогли бы в моей ситуации.

Перевод вопроса: [SVG Animated Graph Arrow @alexandraleigh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40897422/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897422/svg-animated-graph-arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это с помощью `offset-motion` (старый синтаксис: `motion-path`).

Имейте в виду, что это очень экспериментальная функция.

**В настоящее время это работает только в `Chrome`**

Более того, я использую здесь «старый» синтаксис, потому что он работает в chrome, но скоро переключится на новый синтаксис.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #303030;
}
.graph__wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
  svg {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 36px 0px 0px 15px;
  }
}
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 428;
  stroke-dashoffset: 428;
  animation: dash 3s ease-in forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes pm {
  from {
    motion-offset: 0%;
  }
  to {
    motion-offset: 100%
  }
}
#arrow {
  animation: pm 3s ease-in forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  motion-path: path('M2.10546875,95.75 L40.5546875,68.3476562 L55.2109375,81.1796875 L65.2148437,76.3945312 L96.1835937,86.8320312 L131.023438,19.9414062 L142.15625,23.7226562 L183.605469,2.1953125 L211.007812,22.3320312 L234.320312,71.5664062 L234.667969,83.0039062 L244.019531,83.0039062 L247.105469,88.8320312 L312.695312,104.839844');
  motion-rotation:`auto`;
  motion-anchor: center;
}
.description {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  color: lighten(@darkgrey, 50%);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph__wrapper">
  <svg width="315px" height="107px" viewBox="0 0 315 107" version="1.1" style="overflow:visible">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
      <path d="M2.10546875,95.75 L40.5546875,68.3476562 L55.2109375,81.1796875 L65.2148437,76.3945312 L96.1835937,86.8320312 L131.023438,19.9414062 L142.15625,23.7226562 L183.605469,2.1953125 L211.007812,22.3320312 L234.320312,71.5664062 L234.667969,83.0039062 L244.019531,83.0039062 L247.105469,88.8320312 L312.695312,104.839844"
      id="Path-1" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" class="path"></path>



      <polyline id="arrow" points="0,-5 10,0 0,5 1,0" fill="white" />

    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Вы также можете сделать это с помощью `animateMotion`, но анимации `svg` скоро не будет поддерживаться `chrome`. Вам придется рано или поздно переписать свой код.  :-(

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #303030;
}
.graph__wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
  svg {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 36px 0px 0px 15px;
  }
}
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 428;
  stroke-dashoffset: 428;
  animation: dash 3s linear forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.description {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  color: lighten(@darkgrey, 50%);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph__wrapper">
  <svg width="315px" height="107px" viewBox="0 0 315 107" version="1.1" style="overflow:visible">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
      <path d="M2.10546875,95.75 L40.5546875,68.3476562 L55.2109375,81.1796875 L65.2148437,76.3945312 L96.1835937,86.8320312 L131.023438,19.9414062 L142.15625,23.7226562 L183.605469,2.1953125 L211.007812,22.3320312 L234.320312,71.5664062 L234.667969,83.0039062 L244.019531,83.0039062 L247.105469,88.8320312 L312.695312,104.839844"
      id="Path-1" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" class="path"></path>



      <polyline id="arrow" points="0,-5 10,0 0,5 1,0" fill="white">
        <animateMotion rotate="auto" begin="1s" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze">
          <mpath xlink:href="#Path-1" />
        </animateMotion>
      </polyline>

    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```